# How to write files on SD Card from Android API 24+

Tags: android, save, sd-card

I have a big problem. I want to save some files that I download from internet with my application, into my SD card fallowing this path:

**/storage/9016-4EF8/Android/data/com.my.application/files**

But I don't want to hardcode this string inside my code. So how can I do it programmatically?
I have already ask permission to write on external storage.

Currently inside my code there is this piece of code below:

```java
File sdcard = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath() + "/Video scaricati/");
```

But with it, my application saves the files inside:

**/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.application/files/Video scaricati**

that it isn't in my SD card.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the second item returned by

```
File dirs[] =getExternalFilesDirs();
```

Check if the array contains more then one element before use. Not everybody puts a micro SD card in.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing to `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` like this

`new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Video scaricati/");`

Comment: If I do as you said, path become: /storage/emulated/0/Video scaricati 
in which i can't create folder because sdcard.mkdris() returns false. But in any case it still isn't inside SD car.